# Lower bound for $\sum_{v \in V(G)} d(v)\bar{d}(v)$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics

Let $G=(V,E)$ be an $n$-vertex graph with $e$ edges.

For all $v\in V$, $d(v)$ is the degree of $v$, and $\bar{d}(v)$ is the ``non-degree" of $v$, that is, $\bar{d}(v)=(n-1)-d(v)$ (the degree of $v$ in the complement of $G$).

Define $k:=\left\lceil\sqrt{2e+1/4}+1/2\right\rceil$.

I want to show that 
    \begin{align*}
  \sum_{v\in V}d(v)\bar{d}(v)  & \geq  2(n-2)e - \frac{1}{4}\left(k^4-6k^3-(4e-11)k^2+(20e-6)k+4e(e-7)\right) \\
        & =   2(n-2)e - \left(\binom{k}{2}-e\right)^2 + (4k-7)\left(\binom{k}{2}-e\right) - 6\binom{k}{3} 
 \end{align*}

I will explain where this lower bound comes from. I believe that the graph, call it $G^*$, which achieves this lower bound is the following construction:

Take a single vertex from a $k$-clique (a complete graph with $k$ vertices) and remove exactly $r=\binom{k}{2}-e$ edges incident to it. Now add $n-k$ isolated vertices. In that case, there is one vertex of degree $k-r-1$, there are $r$ vertices of degree $k-2$, there are $k-r-1$ vertices of degree $k-1$, and $n-k$ vertices of degree $0$. Hence, for this construction,
    \begin{align*}
  \sum_{v\in V}d(v)\bar{d}(v)  & =  (k-r-1)\left(n-1-(k-r-1)\right) + r(k-2)\left(n-1-(k-2)\right) + (k-r-1)(k-1)\left(n-1-(k-1)\right) \\
        & =  (k-r-1)(n-k+r) + r(k-2)(n-k+1) + (k-r-1)(k-1)(n-k) \\
        & =   n(k^2-k-2r) - (k-r)(k-r-1) - r(k-1)(k-2) - k(k-1)(k-r-1) \\
        & =  2en - 4e + 4e - r^2 +r(4k-3) - k^3 + k^2 \\ 
        & =  2(n-2)e - \left(\binom{k}{2}-e\right)^2 + (4k-7)\left(\binom{k}{2}-e\right) + 4\binom{k}{2} - k^3 + k^2 \\
        & =  2(n-2)e - \left(\binom{k}{2}-e\right)^2 + (4k-7)\left(\binom{k}{2}-e\right) - 6\binom{k}{3}
 \end{align*}

Could someone help me show that $G^*$ is indeed the "best" construction, with "best" meaning that $G^*$ is the unique graph which minimizes $\sum_{v \in V} d(v) \bar{d}(v)$ among all $n$-vertex graphs with $e$ edges. Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not check your equations in detail, but the construction you described does not minimize $\sum_v d(v) \bar{d}(v)$ for the case of $n=5, e=4$.  For this case:

- $k:=\left\lceil\sqrt{2e+1/4}+1/2\right\rceil = \left\lceil\sqrt{8.25}+1/2\right\rceil = 4$
- $r = {k \choose 2} - e = {4 \choose 2} - 4 = 6 - 4 = 2$

So by your construction, you start with the $4$-clique (more commonly denoted $K_4 =$ complete graph of $4$ nodes), pick one of the nodes $w$ (degree $3$) and remove $2$ of its edges.  You end up with a $3$-cycle (the other $3$ unpicked nodes) and a single edge connecting $w$ to one of the nodes in the cycle.  Then since $n=5$ you add $1$ isolated node.  We call this resulting $n=5, e=4$ graph $A$.  The five node degrees of $A$ are: $0, 1, 2, 2, 3$ and the sum is $sum(A) = 0+3+4+4+3 = 14$.

However, the star graph $B$ (where a center node connects to everyone else and those are all the connections) of $n=5, e=4$ has node degrees $1,1,1,1,4$ and the sum is $sum(B) =3+3+3+3+0 = 12 < sum(A)$.

---

I think your construction has a lot of merit, actually, but you missed a key fact:

As you noted, $\bar{d}(v)$ is the degree of $v$ in the complement graph $G' = (V, E')$ (i.e. where $e \in E'$ iff $e \notin E$).  Therefore, the sum $\sum_v d(v) \bar{d}(v)$ is actually the same whether you consider $G$ or $G'$, since the complement of $G'$ is $G$ again.  I.e. $\forall G: sum(G) = sum(G')$.

However, $e' = |E'| = {n \choose 2} - e$, and so if you start your construction procedure with $e$ or start with $e'$ you get two different graphs (obviously).  It turns out they are *not* complements of each other, and can have different values for the sum.

My example is exactly that.  If we use your construction but start with $n=5, e'=6$, we would have:

- $k':=\left\lceil\sqrt{2e'+1/4}+1/2\right\rceil = \left\lceil\sqrt{12.25}+1/2\right\rceil = \lceil 3.5 + 0.5 \rceil = 4$
- $r' = {k' \choose 2} - e' = {4 \choose 2} - 6 = 6 - 6 = 0$

So you would start with $K_4$, remove none of its edges, and simply add a $5$th isolated node.  This graph, $C$, has node degrees are $3,3,3,3,0$ and $sum(C) = 3 + 3+ 3+ 3+ 0 = 12$.  Since $C$ has $6$ edges, it does not qualify, but its complement $C'$ has $4$ edges and *does* qualify, and we already know $sum(C') = sum(C) = 12$.  Now what is $C'$?  It is exactly my star graph $B$.

To conclude: even if you think your procedure is great, after you use it on the given $(n, e)$ to get one graph $A$, you *must* also repeat your procedure starting with $(n, e' = {n \choose 2} - e)$ and get a different graph $C$.  You are guaranteed that $C'$ has $e$ edges.  So you need to pick $\min( sum(A), sum(C') )$.

I think it's an interesting question whether this two-pronged strategy will always minimize the sum for a given $(n,e)$.

Comment: It is interesting that you bring up $e'=\binom{n}{2}-e$ because originally I had defined $k:=\lceil \sqrt{2e'+1/4}+1/2 \rceil$ and $r:=\binom{k}{2}-e$, but I was noticing that for some values of $e'$ this resulted in a negative value for $r$, which did not make sense in this setting. I will look deeper into this two-pronged strategy. I appreciate your insight, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick proof that $G^*$ is optimal. We are trying to maximise $\sum \limits_{v \in V} (n-1)d(v) - d(v)^2$, noting that $\sum \limits_{v \in V} d(v) = 2e$. Since the function $(n-1)x-x^2$ is concave, if any two values of $d(v)$ differed by at least two, moving them closer together by $1$ would improve our sum. So the maximal sum possible would occur when all $d(v)$ were within $1$ of each other and therefore takes one of two possible values, which is exactly the amount obtained by $G^*$.

Comment: I am trying to minimize this sum